# How do I install ubuntu 20.04 LTS without a wired ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

Recently the performance of my 64 bit Windows 10 system has been suffering, so I thought I would look into installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my system.

I downloaded an ISO file for Ubuntu and made a bootable DVD. After Ubuntu started I attempted to visit a website, but it failed. My wireless card specs are "Wireless LAN 802.11b/g/n (up to 150Mbps) Bluetooth 4.0 + LE>. According to Windows my PC is using a Realtek **RTL8188EE** Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC.

My system is not in a room where I have physical contact with the router so I use wi-fi to connect to the internet.

So my question is: during the install process will Ubuntu properly detect the nearby router/wi-fi and let me connect to the router/wi-fi ?

I have been doing some google searching and the answer on this issue is not clear.

Comment: First it's optional to stay connected to a network *during* Ubuntu installation. Now whether your wireless card would work out-of-the-box in Ubuntu 20.04 mainly depends on the card. So please [edit] your question and provide the details of your wireless card.

Comment: One reason Ubuntu/Linux has a 'Try Ubuntu' option, to try out your hardware and check everything works.  The only reason you want network during install is to download updates to save time afterwards.  Use the try option and see if you can connect.

Comment: I created an ubuntu desktop 20.04 CD and booted from the CD. After ubuntu started I attempted to visit a website, but it failed.  My wireless card specs are "Wireless LAN 802.11b/g/n (up to 150Mbps) Bluetooth 4.0 + LE> I am still trying to determine the "brand" of the card.

Comment: according to Windows my pc is using a Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC

Comment: Always [edit] your question to add important info. Comments tend to get overlooked and even in cases deleted easily.

Comment: Once you get the driver sorted, you may need to install some additional packages from the pool directory on the install media to connect: e.g. /pool/w/wpasupplicant.deb (depending upon what wireless security you are using).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, all the wireless cards I have tried recently will connect using Ubuntu. However in the unlikely event that the one you have doesn't work with Ubuntu you can get a usb ethernet adaptor which should say on the box that it is Linux compatible. 
You could check the card in your computer [here](https://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/).

Some cards under Linux have an issue that they disconnect after a while, requiring a reboot to connect again. I found the usb one I have doesn't do this but the internal one in my laptop does.